# How to execute command with partial result from another command?

Tags: bash, environment-modules

I have:

```sh
$ module avail firefox --latest
---------------------------------------------------------- /env/common/modules -----------------------------------------------------------
firefox/83.0
```

I would like to extract the `firefox/83.0` part of the above result into a new command:

```sh
$ module load firefox/83.0
```

This is what I have so far, but it does not seem like I can pipe the result from the `grep` onto the next command:

```sh
$ module avail firefox --latest | grep firefox | echo module load
```

Note: this is on a version of [Modules](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which does not have the `module load app/latest` ability.

Comment: What platform? What Bash version?

Comment: CentOS 7, bash 4.2.

Comment: And what package provides this `module avail` command? Give all necessary reproduction details _in your question_ so we can give the best answer. (With respect, you should know how to form a good question by now!)

Comment: Yeah, hehe, you are right, I added some details in the original post. I figured this was more of a piping-related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to capture only `firefox/83.0`, then use [command substitution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833833/what-does-command-do) to use that result in the next command;

```sh
module load $(module avail firefox --latest | sed -nre 's/^firefox\/[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\0/p'
```

More info on the regex: [How to extract a version number using sed?](https://superuser.com/questions/363865/how-to-extract-a-version-number-using-sed)

---

Using [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html);

```sh
module avail firefox --latest | sed -nre 's/^firefox\/[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\0/p' | xargs module load
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module load "$(module avail firefox --latest | grep -Eo 'firefox\/[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+')"
```

Use the output of the module avail command and then search for firefix, followed by a / and then a digit one or more times, a full stop and then a digit one or more times. use this output as part of the module load command

Comment: Passing `--json` would be much more robust than all this fragile text matching. Though then you need a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

> it does not seem like I can pipe the result from the grep onto the next command:

You can, but you need to use other command, that will read from the pipe and add it as command arguments. As simple as:

```
$ module avail firefox --latest | grep firefox | xargs module load
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the original post, but I tried this, and it gives me: `xargs: module: No such file or directory
`

Comment: So it looks like `module` is either an alias or a bash function.